# Geocoder Request No Response - Fail

Tags: here-api

Is it possible to have the Geocoding API works and sometimes doesn't work for some reason?

Here is the detail what I am trying to request:

```
http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=4&country=Australia&state=Tas&district=Wynyard&postalcode=7321&street=86 Jackson  Street
```

and Here is the demo version from the official website:

```
http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml
      ?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL
      &app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg
      &gen=7
      &housenumber=425
      &street=W+Randolph
      &city=Chicago
```

I am using the Free version of it and I have no idea why it works sometimes and doesn't in other times.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are making a structured address query, by default, all parts of the address need to match. Given that there is no international standard for addresses, the HERE geocoder could be placing parts of the address in an alternative part of the structure.

In your case **Wynard** is recognized as a `city`, not a `district`. Now it is possible you could want this to fail as an invalid address, but it is also possible to tell the Geocoder to be a little more lenient by using the `FlexibleAdminValues` parameter in the `AdditionalData`

see the User Guide [here](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-params-additional.html)

> **FlexibleAdminValues**
>   N (positive integer <= 1). Customizes flexibility in the input values
>   for the admin hierarchy defined in LocationFilterType. The value is a
>   bitmask defining which hierarchies might be swapped without impacting
>   the match level:
>
> - 0: No swapping at all (default). Exact admin hierarchy values are
>     expected as input
> - 1: City and District swapping
>
> Please note this
>   option is for geocoding addresses and needs at least street level
>   input to work as designed. It will not return expected results when
>   the input is a named place only (e.g. city or district name).

So the following url will work for you provided you have a street address:
[http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE&gen=7&**AdditionalData=FlexibleAdminValues,1**&country=Australia&state=tas&district=Wynyard&...etc](http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=7&country=Australia&state=tas&district=Wynyard&&postalcode=7321&street=86%20Jackson%20Street&AdditionalData=FlexibleAdminValues,1)

Comment: thank you for that - Appreciated your time. I didn't realize that Australian district should be converted in city for a general use.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to not use the structured input parameters but let the HERE Geocoder sort out the identification and categorization of the input tokens.
By using the searchtext parameter and providing all your data as the input value the Geocoder can match and score the tokens.
E.g.: http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=7&searchtext=Australia%20Tas%20Wynyard%207321%2086%20Jackson%20Street

Comment: thank you Philip. I will consider this approach as well.